# Moving Chrome Devices to different Org Units: API vs Manual change

Tags: google-admin-sdk, service-accounts

### Does Google use it's own API when using the Google Admin Console to change a chrome device to a different Organizational Unit (OU)?

A school district we support claims that they are having network issues when our service account uses the Directory API to change a chrome device's OU on their behalf. When they moved the devices manually from Google Admin Console, the users claim that their network issues have been resolved.

I have asked the school district to use the user that the service account impersonates in order to make the manual change from Google Admin Console in efforts to replicate the issue, would the user who makes the change be a factor for their network issues?

Is there a difference between using the Directory API and Google Admin Console to change a chrome device's OU?

Comment: Whe you say they are having "network issues" - is there a specific error they obtain?

Comment: There isn't a specific error. An example that they provided was connecting in Google Meets. The manual change improves their connectivity.

I'm inclined to believe that Google uses their own API when using Google Admin Console, but it's hard to confirm that. (i.e. "dogfooding")